# Surprising performance degradation with std::vector and std::string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am processing really large text file in following way:

```
class Loader{
    template<class READER>
    bool loadFile(READER &reader){
        /* for each line of the input file */ {
            processLine_(line);
        }
    }

    bool processLine_(std::string_view line){
        std::vector<std::string> set; // <-- here
        std::string buffer;           // <-- here

        // I can not do set.reserve(),
        // because I have no idea how much items I will put.

        // do something...
    }

    void printResult(){
        // print aggregated result
    }
}
```

The processing of 143,000,000 records take around 68 minutes.

So I decided to do some very tricky optimizations with several `std::array` buffers. Result was about 62 minutes.
However the code become very unreadable so I decided not to use them in production.

Then I decided to do partial optimization, e.g.

```
class Loader{
    template<class READER>
    bool loadFile(READER &reader);

    std::vector<std::string> set; // <-- here
    std::string buffer;           // <-- here

    bool processLine_(std::string_view line){
        set.clear();

        // do something...
    }

    void printResult();
}
```

I was hoping this will reduce malloc / free (new[] / delete[]) operation from `buffer` and from the `set` vector. I realize the strings inside the `set` vector still dynamically allocate memory.

However result went to 83 minutes.

Note I do not change anything except I move `set` and `buffer` on "class" level. I use them only inside `processLine_` method.

Why is that?
Locality of reference?

Only explanation I think about is some strings to be small enough and to fit in SSO, but this sounds unlikely.

Using clang with -O3

Comment: Do you load EVERY record of the file into memory before you start processing it? You could be running out of RAM and your OS decides to use swap space? If you want to reduce the reallocations you could use some kind of heuristic (file size) to predict the approximate number of vector elements you need. Would a database be a better solution than a flat file?

Comment: Do you do anything with the contents of or with `set` or `buffer` at the end of `processLine_`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yes, but this is not important I think. It reads the file then call this function `processLine_` for each line of the txt file. `processLine_` is same in both cases, it doing something like aggregation. I have another method that show the result.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no I do not use them outside the method `processLine_`. All code is unchanged

Comment: @Nick, it may very well be important. How much RAM do you have? How much is this program taking up after it reads 143 million records into memory?

Comment: We can't even see the code you describe.   Try using performance profiler.

Comment: Second a performance profiler. Even random sampling will tell you where you're spending the majority of your computation time. Could be a complex algorithm taking up the time. You could just be burning on blocking I/O operations. Who knows?

Comment: All tests are done on same machine with 32 GB RAM. The file is not loaded into the memory. I can not profile easily because on my laptop i do not have the big file.

Only difference between two versions is move these 2 variables at class level and performance going 10 min down.

Answer (score 0):

I did profile and I found that most of the time is spent in a third party C library.

I supposed this library to be very fast, but this was not the case.

I am still puzzling with the slowdown, but even if I optimize it, it wont make such a big difference.